# VBA code to set on all powerpoint textboxes to the option "Shrink text on overflow"

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am searching for a VBA code that activate the option "Shrink text on overflow" for all textboxes in a PowerPoint document.  I tried this :

```
Sub Change() 
  Dim oSlide As Slide 
  Dim oShape As Shape 
  For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes 
      oShape.TextFrame2.AutoSize = MsoAutoSize.msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape    
    Next oShape  
  Next oSlide   
End Sub
```

But that unfortunately doesn't work. I am a very beginner.
Any thought ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use **msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape** instead of MsoAutoSize.msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape. It's also good to check if the shape actually has a textframe first. This version gets shapes inside groups as well:

```
Sub Change()
    Dim oSlide As Slide
    Dim oShape As Shape
    Dim oSubShape As Shape
    
    For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
            If oShape.Type = msoGroup Then
                For Each oSubShape In oShape.GroupItems
                    If oSubShape.HasTextFrame Then
                        oSubShape.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape
                    End If
                Next oSubShape
            Else
                If oShape.HasTextFrame Then
                    oShape.TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape
                End If
            End If
        Next oShape
    Next oSlide
End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you very much for your answer, and sorry for the trivial side of my question. Unfortunately, the textboxes which are belonging to a group are not modified, but it's a detail. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: I've revised the code to access grouped shapes as well.

Comment: So now, I don't know what else to say. Once again, a big "thank you". With this code, you have a way to change your PowerPoint slide format (for instance from "On screen Show (16:9)" to "Widescreen" size) without any aditional work. It's surprising that PowerPoint does not offer a real mean to resize a slide with the same visual ratio for text and drawings. But thank you very much, Mister Korchok.

Comment: PS : I may go too far, but is there something to add in this code that resizes all drawings, too ? For instance a line of width "w" pt becomes a line of width "w*ratio" pt ? I promise I will really work hard VBA after that in order to avoid additional work to serious people.

Comment: Just this final comment to say that Mr.Korchok deserves all my gratitude for his help, even for people like me who indeed should investigate and work a bit more VBA, but also who can do hardly otherwise because of a lack of time.